# Using channel in `case`

Tags: clojure, core.async

```
(let [a (clojure.core.async/chan)]
  (case a
    a :foo
    :bar))
#=> :bar
```

I would expect `:foo` here. What am I doing wrong?

On the other hand `(condp = chan ...)` does the job.

PS:

Basically I am trying to do following thing:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as a])
(let [chan1 (a/chan 10)
      chan2 (a/chan 10)]
  (a/>!! chan1 true)
  (let [[v c] (a/alts!! [chan1 chan2])]
    (case c
      chan1 :chan1
      chan2 :chan2
      :niether)))
#=> :neither
```

Comment: Never read the source.   ;)    Just read the docs (see below).

Comment: @AlanThompson Removing. I tried to think of something during a bus-layover. Evidently that didn't work out. And I like reading the core source! Lots of interesting stuff in there, although a lot of it is pretty obfuscated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The docs for `case`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case) have the answer

> The test-constants are not evaluated. They must be compile-time
>   literals, and need not be quoted.

The correct solution is to use `cond`:

```
(let [chan1 (ca/chan 10)
      chan2 (ca/chan 10)]
    (ca/>!! chan1 true)
    (let [[v c] (ca/alts!! [chan1 chan2])]
      (spyx (cond
              (= c chan1) :chan1
              (= c chan2) :chan2
              :else :neither))))

;=> :chan1
```

Comment: `(condp = c` is more concise, I suppose

Answer (score 1):

Case uses *unevaluated test-constants* for the left-hand-side of the clause. Plain symbols, like `chan1` here will match only the symbol with the same name, not the value of the local binding with that name; `chan1` will match `'chan1`